# Selenium does not use the scrapy cache

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I use these settings to enable the cache. This works well in scrappy, but not in selenium. It keeps the cache, but ignores after restarting on the same links.

```
'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True,
'HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS': 28800,
'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage',
'HTTPCACHE_GZIP': True,
```

I use these settings to enable the cache. In scrappy, this works well. But when scrapy+selenium is used to get a page, the cache of each page is saved, but not used. Every time after the completion of the work I see in logs

```
'httpcache/firsthand': 12,
'httpcache/store': 12,
```

As if he hadn't seen these pages before and saved them for the first time.
What could be the problem?
I know that selenium can have its own cache enabled. But is it possible to save it to the same place where the scrapy cache stored?